# Buffer size VS File size when reading binary file in Python

Tags: python, file, io, binary

```
buffersize=50000
inflie = open('in.jpg','rb')
outfile = open('out.jpg','wb')

buffer = infile.read(buffersize)

while len(buffer):
    outfile.write(buffer)
    buffer = infile.read(buffersize)
```

I am learning basics of reading / writing binary files in python, and understand this code. 
I'd appreciate any help on understanding this code. 
Thank you!

- Q1: Is 50000 in buffersize equivalent to 50kb? (in.jpg is about 150kb)
- Q2: How is next increment of data (ie. next 50,000 bytes of data) read from the input file?
  (first 50,000 bytes are read and stored before while loop, then are written into output file, 
   how does the next 50,000 bytes are read without any incrementation in range?)
- Q3: len(buffer) means the size of buffer (file object). When does this turn false in while loop?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'incrementation in range' in Q2?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) answers all your questions:

> file.read([size])
>
> Read at most size bytes from the file (less if the read hits EOF before obtaining size bytes). If the size argument is negative or omitted, read all data until EOF is reached. The bytes are returned as a string object. An empty string is returned when EOF is encountered immediately. (For certain files, like ttys, it makes sense to continue reading after an EOF is hit.) Note that this method may call the underlying C function fread() more than once in an effort to acquire as close to size bytes as possible. Also note that when in non-blocking mode, less data than was requested may be returned, even if no size parameter was given.

1: yes. The `size` parameter is interpreted as a number of bytes.

2: `infile.read(50000)` means "read (at most) 50000 bytes from infile". The second time you invoke this method, it will automatically read the next 50000 bytes from the file.

3: `buffer` is not the file but what you last read from the file. `len(buffer)` will evaluate to `False` when buffer is empty, i.e. when there's no more data to read from the file.